# Print the matching line as well as file name

Tags: shell, grep, find

```
find . -name "*.sh" -type f -exec grep -l "mail" {} \;
```

I am using the above statement to find occurances of string `mail` in `sh` file type. I also want to print the usage of string `mail` in that file along with file name. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, if you also want to see the line number and filter out any errors (for instance, Operation not permitted error) that might have encountered during the search.

```
find . -name '*.sh' -type f -exec grep -n mail 2>/dev/null {} +
```